# How to generate timestamp as default value in field in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a CharField and I want to put epoch time as a unique number by default.

```
class Shakf(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True)
    id_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=str(int(time.time())), unique=True)
```

when I reload page I get the same epoch time. Then I tried to put str(int(time.time())) into function.... like this:

```
def epoch_time():
    return str(int(time.time()))

class Shakf(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True)
    id_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=epoch_time(), unique=True)
```

but I get the same result. When I reload page the default value in id_num field the same.
Actually it is changed if I edit model.py or reload server but it doesn't when I reload admin page in browser again

Comment: You should not *call* the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You here have specified as `default` a *value*. Indeed, Python first evaluates the operands. So the `CharField` does *not* know what expression did generate the default value.

You can however specify a callable, like:

```
def default_id_num():
    return str(int(time.time()))

class Shakf(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True)
    id_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=default_id_num, unique=True)
```

Note that we do *not* call the `default_id_num` function, we pass it as a reference.

That being said it is however "odd" to define a `CharField` to store this. You can add a timestamp with a `DateTimeField`, and set it on `auto_now_add`:

```
# more elegant approach

class Shakf(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Or if that is not an option, at least use an `IntegerField`, since now you "lose type constraints" by specifying it as a `CharField`.